# Silicon-based life

Tags: astronomy, biology, chemical-compounds

My question may not be suitable here, because it's more of astrobiology. Life as we know it is carbon based.

1. Is life based on silicon possible?
2. What would the conditions for habitability for silicon based life be?
3. Can both carbon- and silicon-based life co-exist?
4. Is any silicon-based life found on Earth? Can any be grown in the laboratory?

Comment: I think astrobiology questions are completely relevant.  It's a hot topic in astronomy.

Comment: Perhaps better suited for Chemistry.SE?

Comment: Yes, that;s more appropriate

Comment: @Qmechanic (1) Too old to migrate. (2) It's not really ontopic for Chem as well (borderline, I would have had to discuss with the other Chem mods). Possibly Bio. (3) [Due to the astro merger, we _may_ be allowing there](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2804/what-is-our-stance-on-astrobiology)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hypothetical biological analogs, not physics.

Comment: @BrandonEnright astrobiologist are seriously investigating such questions. Maybe it would better fit to astronomy, but the question can no longer be migrated there...

Comment: @Dilaton I agree that it is a valid question worth researching.  It just isn't a physics or astronomy question.

Comment: @BrandonEnright but as dagorym says in the first comment, astrobiology is a valid part of astronomy, even though it is a bit interdiciplinary. And Manisheart also said that due to the merger of astronomy into Physics SE it should be on topic. On meta we just some days ago said that nothing has changed about the on topicness of astronomy questions.

Comment: @Dilaton we don't consider most biophysics questions to be on topic here either.  This is clearly a biology and chemistry question with a tiny bit of astrophysics sprinkled in.  You're welcome to vote to leave open but my vote is for closure.

Comment: Brought up long ago on meta: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2804/what-is-our-stance-on-astrobiology; my own opinion is that this is hypothetical biology, not astrobiology (the latter being about how life as we know it can exist in *specific* extraterrestrial environments).

Comment: @ChrisWhite claiming that you can apply the notion of terrestrial life to extraterrestrial life is way to narrow minded for a scientist. The question is about astrobiology and therefore on topic here as often enough discussed on meta. I wish reviewers could be a bit more tolerant to the way of thinking and methods of others working in fields that are outside their own domain of expertise ...

Comment: I'm voting to reopen. This is best asked in [biology](http://biology.stackexchange.com/) but I don't see the need to close it, and I **really** don't see the point of closing old questions. The worst that can happen is that there is no one here with the expertise to answer it.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty exactly, I generally never saw the point in going after old well received and nicely answered questions to close them today just for the heck and fun of it, either ...

Comment: The question is actually a list of question and while some of them are physics questions the *core* issue is not *and* the existing answers are about chemistry and biology. I'm re-closing it. And the reason for closing old questions is to leave a sign-post for future visitors about what does and does not go.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about xenobiology.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty have you seen what just happend here?

Comment: I strongly disagree with Dmckee unilaterally closing the question just after 5 community members have reopend it and with the notion that any (even the best and by the community most appreciated at the time of asking) questions from the past can be closed any time. This haphazardly puts the whole content of the site on a risk as no questions are save any more.

Comment: Some people reopened it because they felt that it was not off topic (which was what it was closed as). And they may be correct on that. However, look at the question again, it is _four_ questions. Topicality aside, it's objectively broad, @Dilaton. You can vote to reopen again if you feel that it isn't broad. Feel free to bring it up on meta instead. Moderators are entrusted with the binding vote and are allowed to apply it on posts where they are reasonably certain that the post is closeable. In this case, I agree that the post is probably on topic, which is why it was opened, but broad.

Comment: Also, there is a good reason to closing old posts, not for the heck and fun of it. People tend to see posts on this site and ask questions similar to them. Having broad posts / off topic posts / open basic homework posts left open lead to more of the kind being asked.

Comment: Besides, IIRC xenobiology was not allowed on the old Astronomy.SE. This is one of those questions where the astronomy/physics of the post has been tackled and what is left is the biology. But the topicality is debatable.

Comment: @Manishearth the subquestions mentioned in this post are very closely related and about the same issue, such that this does not make the question too broad.There is nothing wrong with organizing questions parts like this. On the contrary it often makes them clearer structured and better readable. I am sorry to say this, but a moderator unilateraly reclosing the question directly only _a few hours_ after 5 community members who know what they are talking about have reopent it, defeats IMHO the whole purpose of community moderation. I can no longer vote to reopen, the system tells me I alr. did.

Comment: Maybe @EmilioPisanty can write a meta post about the issue, as he is much better and more successful than I in such things. The question can now only be reopend by a moderater, as none of the 5 people who think it should not be closed can vote to reopen a second time.

Comment: @Dilaton The first question itself is way too broad, since it first requires you to make some delineation on what one means by life. Nor is it an astrobiology question, it is a general biology question. And the rest are not so related, they could be asked separately. Again, my point about the community members was that not all may have noticed the broadness, they just noticed that it was closed for the offtopicness.

Comment: Was meaning to post this anyway after coming back from class: [moved to meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5563/should-this-astrobiology-question-be-reopened). Please continue further discussion there.

Answer (score 10):

You might be interested in following this link to a discussion of the subject in a NAI featured question:

> The short answer is probably not. Silicon simply doesn't have the moves. While carbon is perfectly comfortable in a variety of different structures (rings, long chains, multi-ring chains, and double-bonded carbon catenations), silicon’s analogous structures are comparatively unstable and sometimes highly reactive. Additionally, such analogous silicon compounds may never occur in nature; the largest silicon molecule ever observed had only six silicon atoms. In contrast, some carbon-based molecules can have tens of thousands!

(Old link [here](http://nai.nasa.gov/astrobio/feat_questions/silicon_life.cfm) unfortunately no longer maintained; available [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20130224025744/http://nai.nasa.gov/astrobio/feat_questions/silicon_life.cfm) through the Wayback Machine.)

Comment: "the largest silicon molecule ever observed had only six silicon atoms. In contrast, some carbon-based molecules can have tens of thousands"- this is very wrong.  Polysiloxanes are long chains $(-Si-O-)_n$.

Answer (score 7):

ONE. This question is very speculative, so I don't think a specific and technical answer is available. Scientists are extremely hesitant to call anything impossible (including both silicon-based life and a conclusive answer to this question). Certainly no one has yet proven that life *can't* be based on silicon, and because it has the same number of valence electrons in its p orbital (four), it is tempting to think that you could just swap out carbon for silicon.

Unfortunately, carbon-based chemical compounds tend to be just the right amount of "floppy." That is, large structures built on carbon like muscle tissues have enough cohesiveness and structure to maintain their architectural integrity when stressed, but enough flexibility to act as, well, muscles. Silicon-based structures, on the other hand, tend to fall on either side of the "Goldilocks" structure- either much too rigid (like silica sand), or much too gooey (silicone, as in breast implants). That is obviously a very broad answer, and I would welcome comments or edits on the subject.

TWO. This is an even longer extrapolation from known science, but we can probably guess. Someone with a stronger chemistry background than I might be able to assist. However, in discussing carbon-based life, we always talk about the critical importance of liquid water. I would imagine that a liquid solvent would be just as critical in the development of silicon-based life. Chemists, would water still be the gold standard for silicon solvents? Some other?

...So, for whatever solvent silicon life used, you'd need temperatures in its liquid range. Besides that, certainly an energy source. Light from a star, or chemical energy, or a heat gradient from the planet's warm core? Hydrogen, oxygen, and nitrogen will likely play the same roles for silicon life as carbon. They are the most abundant chemicals with their respective numbers of valence electrons.

THREE. Humans might be able to live peacefully side-by-side (or spacecraft-by-spacecraft) with silicon-based aliens, but there's a good chance that free carbon-based and silicon-based ecosystems on a single planet would be poisonous to each other. Even if not, they would have to compete for energy and available chemicals as mentioned in the previous question, so I think one would necessarily go extinct as it was out-competed.

->This is a really cool concept! Evolutionary biologists have examined competition and survival of the fittest at the genomic, organism, population, species levels, but survival of the fittest *biochemistry*? You might be able to make some predictions on the basis of efficiency of chlorophyll photosynthesis vs. the silicon energy source.

The only way I could see natural coexistence is if the two ecosystems were almost entirely non-interacting and non-competing. For instance, perhaps a land-, carbon-, and photosynthesis-based ecosystem coexisting with a deep sea or subterranean silicon- and chemical energy-based ecosystem.

FOUR. None whatsoever. Silicon-based life is purely speculative at this point.

Comment: You said carbon based compunds are the right amount of floppy. Won't a more rigid based structure be more suitable for planet with higher gravity?

Comment: @Jonathan, not the right kind of floppy.  :)  This is floppy in a chemical sense (for chemical reactions) not in a structural sense.